# How to factorize a 4th degree polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> I need help to factorise the following polynomial:
>
> $x^4 - 2x^3 + 8x^2 - 14x + 7$

The solution I need to reach is $(x-1)(x^3 - x^2 + 7x - 7)$. I need to factorize to this exactly as it is for a limit question where I cancel out the $(x-1)$ in the numerator and denominator. How do I proceed?

Comment: If I remember correctly, try the rational root theorem.

Comment: ... or Horner's algorithm?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 3):

A brute force approach is to notice that

$$\begin{align} x^4-2x^3+8x^2-14x+7
=&(x^4-x^3)-(x^3-x^2)+7(x^2-2x+1)\\
=&x^3(x-1)-x^2(x-1)+7(x-1)^2\\
=&(x-1)(x^3-x^2+7x-7)\\
=&(x-1)\left(x^2(x-1)+7(x-1)\right)\\
=&(x-1)(x-1)(x^2+7)
\end{align}$$

QED

Comment: I have a random question. I've learnt that QED is for proofs only, so would solving a problem require one? If so I'd like to add QEDs :).

Comment: @Asker123 Latin is not my main strength but "quod erat demonstrandum" means "which is what we wanted to prove" :-)

Comment: Ah...so I guess it can apply here.

Comment: @Asker123 yes because you are answering a question : prove that...

Comment: @marwallx Less loosely translated, the phrase is "that which was to be proved"

Comment: @Soke Extremely loosely (albeit humourously) translated, it's "Quite Easily Done!" :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the coefficients add to $0$, hence $p(1) = 0$. (Instead of noticing this possibly hard to see fact, we might have also chosen to try $1$ because of the rational root theorem)

Now we can use polynomial long division using $x-1$. I'm partial to this method that is essentially the same thing but presented as factoring by grouping.

$x^3(x-1) - x^2 (x-1) + 7x(x - 1) - 7(x - 1) = (x-1)(x^3 - x^2 + 7x - 7)$.

You say this is the solution you need to reach, but we can go further:

We see that the roots still add to zero, so  we can do the same process:

$(x-1)(x^2(x-1) + 7(x-1)) = (x-1)^2 (x^2 + 7)$

Comment: He's not asking for roots. I don't think we need that last line.

Comment: @MXYMXY Good catch

Comment: This makes a lot of sense OP thanks

Comment: Exactly...Rational Root Theorem. When you type an answer and discard it, when someone else does it faster. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One may recognize the factorization of the polynomial(#): $$y^2+8y+7=(y+1)(y+7)$$

Also(^)
$$-2x^3-14x=-2x(x^2+7)$$

From (#), when $y=x^2$, we obtain(*)
$$x^4+8x^2+7=(x^2+1)(x^2+7)$$

Combine(*) and (^), we have
\begin{align}
x^4-2x^3+8x^2-14x+7&=(x^2+1)(x^2+7)-2x(x^2+7)\\&=(x^2-2x+1)(x^2+7)\\&=(x-1)^2(x^2+7)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)=(x-1)Q(x)$, or $Q(x)=\dfrac{P(x)}{x-1}$, where $Q(x)$ is the requested polynomial.

The independent term is $q_0=Q(0)=\dfrac{P(0)}{0-1}=\color{green}{-7}$.

The coefficient of the next term can be found by deriving, with $q_1=Q'(0)=\dfrac{P'(0)}{0-1}-\dfrac{P(0)}{(0-1)^2}=\color{green}{7}$.

Then $2!\,q_2=Q''(0)=\dfrac{P''(0)}{0-1}-2\dfrac{P'(0)}{(0-1)^2}+2\dfrac{P(0)}{(0-1)^3}=-2=2!\,(\color{green}{-1})$ and $3!\,q_3=Q'''(0)=\dfrac{P'''(0)}{0-1}-3\dfrac{P''(0)}{(0-1)^2}+6\dfrac{P'(0)}{(0-1)^3}-6\dfrac{P(0)}{(0-1)^4}=6=3!\,\color{green}{1}$.

Comment: It works, but I wouldn't recommend that method, it is too inefficient ! ;-)